# If two vertices are non-adjacent in Petersen graph then they have exactly one comon neighbour.

Tags: graph-theory

How do I prove that if two vertices are non-adjacent in Petersen graph then they have exactly one common neighbour.

Comment: By inspection ?

Answer (score 1):

This rather depends on your definition of the Petersen graph. One definition is
that the ten vertices are labelled $P_A$ where $A$ runs through the two-element
subsets of $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$, and that $P_A$ and $P_B$ are adjacent iff $A\cap B
=\emptyset$. If $P_A$ and $P_B$ are non-adjacent, then $|A\cup B|=3$, and
the only $P_C$ adjacent to both is with $C=\{1,2,3,4,5\}\setminus(A\cup B)$.